# How to get the real path of the embedded file in the Outlook VSTO mail body?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXBFq.png)
By obtaining the email body of the Outlook.MailItem type, the html text of the email is obtained, but it is found that the path of the picture contains cid, How do I parse the cid so that the email body can display the image normally on the webBrowser control?

I don't know how to parse out the real path

Comment: There is no real path. That's the point. It's embedded in the email, not a separate file.